# copy constructor, pass by value and return by value, chain operation, compiler

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator, pass-by-value, chaining

I wrote this program in two different compilers and I got two different results:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point {
public:
  int n;
  Point() { n = 0; }
  Point operator= (Point p) { return *this; }
  Point(const Point& p) { cout<<"copy\n"; }
  ~Point() { cout<<"Destruct\n"; }
};

int main() {
  Point p1, p2, p3;
  p1 = p2 = p3;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiler 1:

```
copy
copy
copy
Destruct
Destruct
Destruct
Destruct
Destruct
Destruct
```

Compiler 2:

```
copy
copy
Destruct
copy
Destruct
Destruct
Destruct
Destruct
Destruct
```

I know that some compilers optimize the pass/return by value of an object from a function by not calling the copy constructor. Is this the reason for the difference between the two results?

**More importantly, why is the copy constructor called twice for the p2 = p3 part of the code but only once for p1 = ... ?**

I don't do much OO programming using C++, that is why I am confused with this simple question. I really appreciate some hints

Comment: This `Point operator= (Point p) { return *this; }` is not what an assignment opertor should look like. And you haven't instrumented it.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Neil. I am aware that this not the correct way of writing the assignment operator. I just wanna know how the compiler handles this code and why

Comment: The compilers probably comply with standards of different vintage (or one is less complete in its compliance with a recent standard than another).   Recent standards require that temporaries persist through the expression that created them, but older standards were less specific on lifetime of temporaries so compilers could choose to destruct a temporary earlier.     Copy elision will also complicate things, but isn't the case here (same number of temporaries being created in both cases, just their lifetime differs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment operator should return `Point &` not `Point`, and it should take the parameter as a reference, too :

```
Point &operator = (const Point &p) { return *this; }
```

Otherwise, unnecessary copying may occur.  Most likely, one copy is created going in to the assignment operator, then the returned value is copied to both `p2` and `p1`.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Sid. I know the correct way of writing the function (pass by reference and return by reference to avoid unnecessary copying and chaining). However, I am just baffled why the copy constructor is called twice for p2 = p3 and one for p1 = copy of returned object ?

Comment: @user Because `Point operator= (Point p) { return *this; }` makes a copy of its parameter and again for its return value.

Comment: Most likely, one copy is created going in to the assignment operator, then the returned value is copied to both `p2` and `p1`.